# How to get pgdir in xv6?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, xv6

I'm trying to add a system call to xv6 that provides the translated physical address given a virtual address. Combining the following function definitions, I have written a system call. Functions used:

```
static pte_t *
walkpgdir(pde_t *pgdir, const void *va, int alloc)       -- vm.c
```

---

```
char*
uva2ka(pde_t *pgdir, char *uva)    --vm.c
```

---

Here is my code:

proc.c

```
int addr_translate(char* virtual_address)
{
    int physical_address;
    pde_t *pgdir,*pgtab,*pde;

    //must initialise pgdir

    pde = &pgdir[PDX(virtual_address)];
    if(*pde & PTE_P){
    pgtab = (pte_t*)P2V(PTE_ADDR(*pde));
    }
    else
    {
    cprintf("\n PTE Not Present! - Invalid Virtual address\n");
    return -1;
    }
    cprintf("\n ----------------- \n");
    cprintf(" Page Directory Entry (PDE): %d\n",*pde);
    cprintf(" PTE_P : %d\n",PTE_P);
    cprintf("\n ----------------- \n");

    //uva2ka
    pte_t *pte;
    pte = &pgtab[PTX(virtual_address)];
    physical_address=(char*)P2V(PTE_ADDR(*pte));

    cprintf(" --PHYSICAL ADDRESS-- %d\n",physical_address);

    return 0;

   }
```

sysproc.c

```
char*
sys_addr_translation(char *s)
{
  argstr(0, &s);
  addr_translate(s);
  return s;
}
```

addr_translation.c (From where I'm invoking my system call)

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf(1,"\n ----ADDRESS TRANSLATION----\n");
    char *virtual_addr;
    virtual_addr=argv[1];

    printf(1,"\n Entered virtual address: %s\n",virtual_addr);
    printf(1,"\n Status from system call: %s",addr_translation(virtual_addr));
    exit();
}
```

Basically, I'm taking the virtual address as an argument from the user and passing it to my system call. I'm retrieving the virtual address using `argstr()` in my system call.

The part where I'm stuck is, I'm not able to understand how to initialise pgdir (page directory) in my `add_translate()` function in `proc.c`.

Answer (score 0):

For the line: physical_address=(char*)P2V(PTE_ADDR(*pte));
I think this should be V2P, because what you want is physical address, right?
:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `struct proc *curproc = myproc();` and then you'll have access to the pgdir through `curproc->pgdir`.